# jQuery show respective on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set of buttons, and on click of each button it will show the respective div and hide the all other sibling items. I'm an absolute beginner to jQuery so I come across with a solution but sibling div's won't hide. and also can this be done via IF/ELSE ?

```js
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.course-design-custom').addClass('d-none');
});

$('#showMcq').click(function() {
  $('#McqView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showOe').click(function() {
  $('#OeView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showAs').click(function() {
  $('#AssessmentView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showLt').click(function() {
  $('#LearningTaskView').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showMcq">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs">Assessment</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom" id="McqView">
    MCQ
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView">
    Open Ended
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView">
    Learning Task
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView">
    Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is you problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `attribute` to you `button` that tells what element it should work with.

```
<button id="showAs" target="AssessmentView">Assessment</button>
```

Then you jQuery could look like:

```
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  var target = "#" + $(this).attr("target");

  var selected = $(target);
  selected.siblings().addClass("d-none");
  selected.removeClass("d-none");
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  var target = "#" + $(this).attr("target");

  var selected = $(target);
  selected.siblings().addClass("d-none");
  selected.removeClass("d-none");
});
```

```css
.container .div {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showMcq" target="McqView">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe" target="OeView">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt" target="LearningTaskView">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs" target="AssessmentView">Assessment</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom" id="McqView">
    MCQ
  </div>

  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView">
    Open Ended
  </div>

  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView">
    Learning Task
  </div>

  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView">
    Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify this function

```
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  $(".course-design-custom").addClass('d-none');
});
```

```js
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  $(".course-design-custom").addClass('d-none');
});

$('#showMcq').click(function() {
  $('#McqView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showOe').click(function() {
  $('#OeView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showAs').click(function() {
  $('#AssessmentView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showLt').click(function() {
  $('#LearningTaskView').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="showMcq">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs">Assessment</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom" id="McqView">
    MCQ
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView">
    Open Ended
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView">
    Learning Task
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView">
    Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

**A Better Approach**

Keep a data-id on the buttons and use this id to target the element that you want to show on its click.

```js
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  $(".course-design-custom").addClass('d-none');
  var dataId = $(this).attr("id");
  $(".container").find("[data-id='" + dataId + "']").removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="showMcq">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs">Assessment</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom" id="McqView" data-id="showMcq">
    MCQ
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView" data-id="showOe">
    Open Ended
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView" data-id="showLt">
    Learning Task
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView" data-id="showAs">
    Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add 'd-none' class for div using function like below and after that use `removeClass`.

```js
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.course-design-custom').addClass('d-none');
});

$('#showMcq').click(function() {
  hidedivfirst();
  $('#McqView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showOe').click(function() {
  hidedivfirst();
  $('#OeView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showAs').click(function() {
  hidedivfirst();
  $('#AssessmentView').removeClass('d-none');
});

$('#showLt').click(function() {
  hidedivfirst();
  $('#LearningTaskView').removeClass('d-none');
});

function hidedivfirst() {
  $('.row').addClass('d-none');

}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showMcq">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs">Assessment</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom" id="McqView">
    MCQ
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView">
    Open Ended
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView">
    Learning Task
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView">
    Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

update your html , script and css like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("button").click(function(){
                var cls = $(this).attr("class");
                $(".course-design-custom").removeClass("active");
                $("#"+cls).addClass("active");
                return false;
            });

        });

</script>

<style>

    .course-design-custom{ display:none; }
    .course-design-custom.active{ display:block; }

</style>

<button id="showMcq" class="McqView">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe" class="OeView">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt" class="LearningTaskView">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs" class="AssessmentView">Assessment</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom active" id="McqView">
    MCQ
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView">
    Open Ended
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView">
    Learning Task
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView">
    Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use [JQuery UI Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) it will handle every thing for you and you don't need to manage class and no need to write extra javascript or jquery for this just follow structure and use method `$("#tabs").tabs();});`

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use data attributes to target the div you would like to display on click. Inorder to distinguish each button clicks in the $('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {}); , you can use $(this).attr('id'); which will give you the id of the buttons clicked in that function.

```js
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  $('.course-design-custom').addClass('d-none');
  var viewCourse = $(this).data('view');
  $('#'+viewCourse).removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```css
.d-none{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showMcq" data-view="McqView">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe" data-view="OeView">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt" data-view="LearningTaskView">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs" data-view="AssessmentView">Assessment</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom" id="McqView">
    MCQ
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView">
    Open Ended
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView">
    Learning Task
  </div>
  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView">
    Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your *HTML* suggest that you can use index to hide/show the elements:

```js
$('#showMcq, #showOe, #showLt, #showAs').click(function() {
  var idx = $('button').index(this);
  $('.course-design-custom').hide(); //hide all
  $('.course-design-custom').eq(idx).show(); //show only by matching the index 
});
```

```css
.d-none{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showMcq">MCQ</button>
<button id="showOe">Open Ended</button>
<button id="showLt">Learning Task</button>
<button id="showAs">Assessment</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row course-design-custom" id="McqView">
      MCQ
  </div>

  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="OeView">
      Open Ended
  </div>

  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="LearningTaskView">
      Learning Task
  </div>

  <div class="row course-design-custom d-none" id="AssessmentView">
     Assessment
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[.parent() API](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(this).parents('.course-design-custom').addClass('d-none');
```

This function is used in the wrong way, you can try it like this

```
$('.course-design-custom').addClass('d-none');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xqt2rws/13/)